# Payment method wont show me form in backoffice order

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, backend, payment

I've installed a new payment method from nps in magento 1.9.3.6 .
The problem is that I need to use it for backend orders. But when i select it, it doesn't show the payment form.
Here's an image.

[image: NPS selected on backoffice order]

I don't know if there's any display that is set to false or something similar in the code.
PD: In the frontend of the page NPS works ok.
This is the link of the module: [NPS MAGENTO](https://github.com/Ingenico-NPS-Latam/nps-plugin-magento)

Comment: it needs to have the code to display on the admin - can you post a link to the module code?

Comment: There you go https://github.com/Ingenico-NPS-Latam/nps-plugin-magento